# How to create a new user in SharePoint when the user doesn't exist in AD?

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, migration

I have to import a lot of old data into SharePoint. In this data, I need to create a lot of users who are no longer in AD. Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Cheers

Comment: Can you edit the question to include where the data is coming from and what it is? For example, list items from another SharePoint site, or documents from a file system, or something/somewhere else?

Comment: Will you be writing a program to do this? Otherwise, I think this belongs on serverfault.

Comment: Yes I want to do this by code..

Answer (score 1):

The options I can come up with:

- Recreate the users in Active Directory and disable the accounts
- Attribute the files to a generic account
- Tie into a SQL database for user accounts in addition to Active Directory

On a sidenote, I've seen it to be a best practice to never delete users from Active Directory due to issues like these.  Instead, just disable the accounts and move them to an out of the way OU.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible as you are really trying to create orphaned users. Better just revert these users to the System Account - that is what I did when I last migrated a SharePoint 2003 farm to MOSS 2007.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSVDE to import a comma separated file, or dsadd command to add each user. See this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778414(WS.10).aspx) for details.

Comment: the problem is all these users have already left the organization. So add them back to ad is not a good option. but for historical reason, these name do need to appear in the sharepoint.